# How to insert elements with JavaScript whenever some specified character exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Current:

```
<p id="article">忙著端出 高階 DSLR 產品的 Nikon ，總算想到了在 兩年半之後 更新自己的入門系列數位單眼相機，端出 Nikon D3400。很好的產品</p>
```

I would like to split the text whenever some specified characters "，", "。" exist  (note: could be other characters) and insert  element with class.

Target:

```
<p id="article">
    <span class="seg1">忙著端出 高階 DSLR 產品的 Nikon ，</span>
    <span class="seg2">總算想到了在 兩年半之後 更新自己的入門系列數位單眼相機，</span>
    <span class="seg3">端出 Nikon D3400。</span>
    <span class="seg4">很好的產品</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41423602/edit) your question so as to include the code you have already tried, and an explanation of how it is not working.

Comment: a simple web search of "javascript split" would have at least gotten you a starting point. Some basic research and showing your attempts to solve your own issue is expected here

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as example : https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/7uvu2uhq/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var article=$("#article").html();
   var articleArr=article.split(/，|。/);
   var html="";
   for(var i=0;i<articleArr.length;i++){
      html+="<span class='seg"+(i+1)+"'>"+articleArr[i]+"</span>";
   }

   $("#article").html(html);
});
```

Comment: <span class="seg1">忙著端出 高階 DSLR 產品的 Nikon </span>

Comment: It spit and add to html. You want it to display as text?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Kindly ignore the previous comments.

Just realized that output with using your code "，" was stripped at seg1.
In seg 3, "。" cannot be split.

Not quite the same as my target code

Comment: Also, I see a duplicated text was appended at the code

Comment: I see the characters "，" and "。" are removed. Are there any ways to keep them?

Comment: I have updated code to maintain character. You can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/7uvu2uhq/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method within the jQuery [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method callback.

```
var i = 0;
$('#article').html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/[^，]+，?/g, function(m){ 
    return '<span class="seg' + ++i + '">' + m + '</span>'; 
  });
})
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/eL8sjyba/)

Comment: it works well to split the text.
But it the variable i cannot be increased well and all the class are the same as "seg1"

Comment: The whole articles just vanish after using the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Easier way of the codes above:

```
var replace=[
[" ," , "</span><span>"],
[" °" , "</p><p>"]
];

var article=document.getElementById("article");
for(index in replace){
  article.replace(replace[index][0],replace[index][1]);
}
```